# How to change name in the messages section?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

On StackOverflow jobs, I changed my profile name to "Nav", but when I see the messages inbox section, my full name and email ID is displayed. A recruiter who messaged me, did so by using my full name, which means it's visible to them too. How do I change that full name  displayed, to "Nav"? Perhaps StackOverflow's developers should sync that name field with the profile name.

Comment: What do you have under the "Real name" section of your account settings?

Comment: It's my actual name. The linked question solved the issue. I found the field that contained my full name. Thanks.